# Generating new objects from findViewById() method

Tags: android

I would like to create a new xml file (beside the main one) in the layout folder to describe some views.

My idea is to use the findViewById method to find the view style that I want (differentiating them by id) and to generate another instance of the object.

Is this possible with android API means?

I feel that maybe it is not a 'correct design' choice, but it would save me from the pain to create the styles programmatically.

I know that I can create a copy method, but that it is exactly what I am trying to avoid because managing xml files would be simpler.

Comment: `LayoutInflater` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: Thank you. I briefly looked at some examples and this seems the solution.